# How to find out whether a particular device has SIM Hardware support?

Tags: android, tablet, telephony

I wanted to disable features related to CALL and SMS in my application based on whether SIM hardware is present or not. Now a beginners approach towards this will be checking the Phone type using :

```
if (telephonyManager1.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
```

If true then its supported.

Everything was fine until i came across Sony Tablet S which has a SIM support only for Data and Messaging. No voice support. So for this device i need to disable only CALL feature but continue with SMS support.
 Sony tablet returns TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE so i can`t use the above methods. 
Also ,

```
telephonyManager1.getSimState();
```

returns 1 i.e SIM_STATE_ABSENT which is also same in case of HTC FLYER which has no support for SIM hardware itself.

So is there any way in which i can come to know if SIM hardware is there(irrespective of SIM card inserted or not) ?

Comment: so your end goal is to know whether call is supported? why do you care about sim

Comment: VOIP call over WiFi is not supported?

Comment: @nandeesh - my goal is to know whether both call and sms are supported individually. To be very precise i wanna know if there is a SIM Card Slot available.

Comment: again i get that you want call and sms are supported but why do you need sim card slot. Most Cdma phones do not have sim card slot

Comment: @nandeesh - I m dealing with tablets only here. And just checking call support is not the case. my case is checking is sms supported in case if call is not supported. Thats the case of sony tablet s. It supports sms but no call.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
boolean hasTelephony=pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

Edit:

Try using

```
TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()
```

If this returns null then you wont have telephony feature. Have not tried. give it a shot

Comment: -i checked on HTC Flyer and Sony Tablet S...both return false :( . I am surprised actually. the docs say,
"Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device has a telephony radio with data communication support."

this sony tablet supports sms messaging though.

Comment: even if it does return null thats doesnt helps me out here ..cause i m getting whether CALL is supported or not with the help of TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE.... What i need is to check if SMS is supported or not