# Android check if device is capable of connecting to cellular data network

Tags: android, android-networking

Android check if device is capable of connecting to cellular data network (2G/3G/4G etc).

I know that there are APIs to check if SIM is present or not, but i want to know if device is capable of connecting to any cellular data networks or if device is having any SIM slot available?

Does android provides any api for this?

** UPDATE ** :
If this the possible way of getting if device is capable of connecting to mobile network.

```
int phoneType = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getPhoneType();
if(phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
{
     // No phone related functionality supported, phones and data network.
}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001863/how-to-find-out-whether-a-particular-device-has-sim-hardware-support and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429722/how-to-detect-if-device-is-capable-of-calling-and-messaging?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
networkInfo.isConnected() && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
```

?

Last line will return if it is connected and it is cellular.

Comment: This is for in general connectivity of the device, here we don't check if device is capable of connecting to cellular data network. it will return true if device is connected to wifi.

Comment: Changed to identify cellular. 

You can also check type of cellular data type by networkInfo.getSubtype(), in TelephonyManager you have constants for example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#NETWORK_TYPE_LTE